# About Bootstrap and responsiveness

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

## The question

I created a website for a local sports community and used bootstrap v4 for it. The main part of the website is almost done, so I am currently dealing with the media breakpoints, to make the website responsive. However I came up with a few problems:

#### 1st Which breakpoints should I use?

Iam currently using the ones

```
/* Smartphones */
@media only screen and (max-width : 991px) {


/* Large devices */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {

}

/* Extra large devices */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {}
```

and I would like to know how suitable they are.

#### 2nd How to center an element?

The website not only consits of the main-page, but some sub-pages as well.
I want the element `<div class="text-container">` to have the same distance to the `nav` and the `footer` so that the whole website combinded fills the whole screen (on desktop, the sub-page mobile is a WIP) and not be scrollable.

The concerning sub-page is:
http://www.sv-velber-fussball.de/Tim/mannschaften/herren/1herren.html

#### 3rd How to make Bootstrap's carousel responsive?

On the page http://www.sv-velber-fussball.de/Tim/index.html I use a carousel with three images. On mobile, or even smaller desktops, the carousel's images don't fill up the whole screen area.

## What I've tried:

#### concerning the 2st point:

```
top: 50%;
-ms-transform: translate(-50%);
transform: translate(-50%);
```

```
margin-top: X%;
margin-bottom: X%;
```

#### concerining the 3rd point:

`height: 100%;`

`height: 100vh;`

## Code

The code is online at the given adressess. The css-file style.css is the main one, sub.css is for the sub-pages and in columns.css are the .col-x classes defined.

Comment: 1st Which breakpoints should I use?  plz use this one.. @media only screen and (max-width : 991px)..  bcoz u are already completed desktop.. for max-width used for responsive purpose only

Comment: @Manikandan2811 thanks, I'll update the code as soon, as the other issues are fixed.

Comment: Remaining points are cleared?

Comment: Give me more information on what do you mean please.

Comment: You are asked 3 points.. i cleared only first point.. remaining 2 points are cleared or shall i explain?

Comment: I understand. The other 2 post have not been answered yet and need clarification.

Comment: 2nd How to center an element? - for aligning vertically center u can add the classname "align-self-center".. for example, <div class="col-55 align-self-center"></div>

Comment: the usage of the class changes nothing to the looks.

Comment: sorry.. .text-container p {margin-bottom:0px;} plz add this in style and check

Comment: unfortunately still nothing. I'd rather like to use margins or someting.

Comment: or u can modify the style.css at line no:101.. margin-bottom:70px are in.. u have to change this to 0px;

Comment: Now theres is no space between nav, the text-conatiner and the footer, which makes sense. How to preceed now?

Comment: Do u want whitespace between the nav,text-container,footer?

Comment: Yes. So much whitespace that the nav is at the start of the screen and the nav perfectly aligns with the end, so that there isn't any content outisde of the screen.

Comment: Do u want to add space or remove the space?

Comment: Add the same space between nav and text-container AND text-container and footer, so that the text-container has the equal amount of whitepsace above and below it.

Answer (score 1):

For third point change the below codes..

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image:url(./assets/img/carousel/1.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image:url(./assets/img/carousel/2.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image:url(./assets/img/carousel/3.jpg);"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It now fits the screen, which is awesome! hHowever is the image to big, so that only the upper corner is visible :c

Comment: Just change the size of the images then?

Answer (score 0):

Plz add this codes..

**css**

```
.text-container {
    padding: 70px 0px 90px;
}
```

**HTML**
Please remove the "col-100" class for bottom of the page

```
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
```

Comment: I am now using a sticky footer. Thank you anyway!